# Startup Screen Flashes Pink

Tags: macos, startup, macbook-pro

During boot, I see the gray screen with the Apple logo, then the entire screen flashes pink for a couple seconds before boot continues normally.

Is this a problem/symptom of something?

MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013, Intel HD Graphics 4000

Comment: do you have any peripherals plugged in?

Comment: I see something like this, not pink, but a weird static/snow pattern. I haven't noticed any other symptoms myself though.

Comment: Thanks for your replies -- no peripherals (other than magic mouse).

Comment: This is sometimes an indication of HDCP handshake failure for HDMI attached displays.  I haven't seen it on an attached laptop display before though.